# Можно ли использовать переписанный минифицированный js файл платной библиотеки в коммерческих целях?

Tags: лицензирование

Всем привет! Существует заброшенная бесплатная библиотека, которая позволяет рендерить изображение на canvas. На днях нашел форк, где разработчик ее усовершенствовал. Условия лицензии таковы, что этот форк можно использовать, однако не в коммерческих целях. На гитхабе лежит минифицированный файл. Можете считать меня психом, но я построчно переписал этот файл в читабельный вид, сверяя переменные. Вопрос следующий. Если я буду использовать этот код в своем коммерческом проекте, могу ли я получить за это по шапке?

Comment: Сложный вопрос, но скорее всего да, если код остался один в один.

Comment: Код аналогичен оригинальной библиотеке на 70%, остальное - кастомные функции разработчика, который ее поддерживает на данный момент